# Ограничение движения объекта по форме

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Есть форма на C++, в которой по нажатию кнопки двигается другая кнопка, как сделать границы, за которые эта кнопка выходить не будет?

```
private:
System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e)
{
    button2->Top -= 5;
}

private:
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e)
{
    static bool x = true;
    if (x) {
        timer1->Enabled = true;
        x = 0;
        button1->Text = "Stop";
    } else {
        timer1->Enabled = false;
        x = 1;
        button1->Text = "Start";
    };
}
```

Comment: Это в С++ или в Windows Form?

Comment: Windows Forms.

Comment: В методе, двигающем кнопку, указать границы, покажите код.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте TableLayoutPanel, но я не помню, правильно ли, забыл. Вот для C#

```
private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox2.Location = 
            new Point((Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X - 55), (Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y - 55));
}

private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (status == true)
        pictureBox2.Location = 
            new Point((Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X - 55), (Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y - 55));
}

private void pictureBox2_LocationChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBox2.Location.Y <= pictureBox1.Location.Y || pictureBox2.Location.X <= pictureBox1.Location.X)
        status = false;
    if ((pictureBox2.Location.Y >= (pictureBox1.Location.Y + pictureBox1.Height - 50) || pictureBox2.Location.X >= (pictureBox1.Location.X + pictureBox1.Width - 100)))
        status = false;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X) >= (pictureBox1.Location.X + 50))
        status = true;
    if ((Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y) >= (pictureBox1.Location.Y + 25))
        status = true;
}
```

Только это для pictureBox, поменяйте на Button1. С++ и C# похожи. Подредактируйте код и должно получиться!

Comment: А в самом коде нельзя?

Comment: Ну наверно можно,но я незнаю

Comment: А где здесь именно само ограничение?